# Return a file based on provided path

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a media organiser application written in windows forms C# and I have given the functionality to create different 'playlists'.

I have two tables inside a local SQL database -

Playlist - this just has different playlists created, with a simple name and id field.

Files - this is a table which has a file name, the full path of the file and the assigned Playlist_ID.

What I've got so far is the functionality to get user selected playlist and to retrieve the assigned media files in that playlist.

What I'm struggling on is to find a way to retrieve a file based on a provided path of the file which then I can display inside the listview.

My code so far..

```
if (playlistListView.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
{
    string _SelectedItem = playlistListView.SelectedItems[0].Text;
     if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_SelectedItem))
         {
        IList<PlaylistData> _PlaylistData = __MediaManager.GetPlaylists();
          {
PlaylistData _SelectedPlaylistData = _PlaylistData.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == _SelectedItem);
                    if (_SelectedPlaylistData != null)
                    {
                        IList<MediaFilesData> _Files = __MediaManager.GetFiles(_SelectedPlaylistData.Playlist_ID);
                        if (_Files != null && _Files.Count > 0)
                        {
                            //here I need to get the actual files which match the path inside _Files object.
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: There are lots of file access mechanisms inside System.IO. (File, FileInfo, Directory,  Path...)

Comment: @Flydog57 having looked at System.IO on Microsoft website I can't exactly find a function that will retrieve the file based on a provided path.

Comment: Really? What's in the file (text or a bunch of bytes) and how much is in the file (can you afford to read it all in one gulp)? If it's text, and it's gulp-able, did you see `File.ReadAllText` or `File.ReadAllLines`? For other choices see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/index. If you google for any of the words in your problem, you should find a solution